# Zapier Cli - Is there a way to send line items from Shopify to my Zapier CLI App?

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopify, zapier, zapier-cli

Just like [this](https://zapier.com/apps/google-sheets/integrations/shopify/13767/send-line-items-from-new-shopify-paid-orders-to-google-sheets-as-multiple-rows) zap, how can i accept line items from Shopify app into my Zapier Cli app? What should be the inputFields and how should I map them to Shopify line items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set up your action to accept line items, you'll want to designate one of the `inputFields` in your action as the "line items" field. This field should have a `children` property with an array of line item fields (using the same field schema).

For example, let's say your app has a "Create Invoice" action. The `inputFields` might look something like this:

```
inputFields: [
    {key: 'customerAccountId', required: true, type: 'string'},
    {key: 'dueDate', required: true, type: 'datetime'},
    {key: 'line_items', children: [
        {key: 'item_name', type: 'string'},
        {key: 'price', type: 'number'},
        {key: 'quantity', type: 'number'}
    ]},
]
```

More info in the field schema docs: https://zapier.github.io/zapier-platform-schema/build/schema.html#fieldschema

This allows your action to accept line items from any app with a trigger that gives line items. The trigger description should say whether it has line item support—you can see a few examples from Shopify here: https://zapier.com/apps/shopify/integrations#triggers-and-actions

Comment: Thanks @Juan Vazquez, this was exactly what I wanted.